# Checking if ASCII is in two ranges

Tags: c#

```
byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myInput);    
while (I < ASCIIValues.Length)
{
    {
        if ((ASCIIValues[I] > 65 & ASCIIValues[I] < 90) || (ASCIIValues[I] > 97 & ASCIIValues[I] < 122))
        {

        }
        ASCIIValues[I] = 32;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ASCIIValues[I]);
    I++;
}
```

This is what I have now and I am trying to make sure the string the user enters (my Input) is within the ranges of being a letter only. I am trying to remove all punctuation and special characters as well as numbers. I is equal to 0 and is used to iterate through the array. Changing all unwanted characters to a space is because further down in my code I am removing the spaces anyway.

When running the code every returned ASCII value is `32`. This makes no sense as letters should return the corresponding ASCII value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(As L.B says, there are simpler ways of doing this - but it's worth examining why your current code doesn't work, too.)

> When running the code every returned ASCII value is 32

Yes, it would do. Look closely at your loop:

```
while (I < ASCIIValues.Length)
{
    {
        if ((ASCIIValues[I] > 65 & ASCIIValues[I] < 90) || (ASCIIValues[I] > 97 & ASCIIValues[I] < 122))
        {

        }
        ASCIIValues[I] = 32;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ASCIIValues[I]);
    I++;
}
```

You're doing *nothing* within the `if` block, and instead you're *unconditionally* setting `ASCIIValues[I]` to 32.

Additionally:

- I'd use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop.
- You don't really need to convert the characters to bytes here; each ASCII character has the same Unicode value anyway.
- Specifying the characters using character literals (`'A'` etc) would make the code simpler to read
- You should adopt .NET naming conventions to make your code more idiomatic
- You should use `&&` instead of `&` here

Comment: I thought that placing it there would mean that 'ASCIIValues[I] = 32' would then run as the loop comes across a non-letter.

Comment: I tried using a foreach loop and 'ASCIIValues[I] = 32;' would return that the index was out of the bounds of the array

Comment: @buckeye269: Ah, yes - of course if you're going to use the index, you do need a straight `for` loop. But no, with that placement, you're basically ignoring the `if` condition completely. You're saying, "If this condition is met... do nothing. Then, either way, set the value to space."

Comment: I learned though that putting it within the brackets just under the if is for when it is true and right after the brackets is for when it is false.

Comment: @buckeye269: No, for that you need an `else` clause.

Answer (score 7):

> I am trying to make sure the string the user enters (my Input) is within the ranges of being a letter only

There may be simpler ways to do this.

```
bool isAllLetter = yourString.All(char.IsLetter);
```

> I am trying to remove all punctuation and special characters as well as numbers

```
var cleanStr = String.Join("", str.Where(char.IsLetter));
```